# quit the Selenium web driver session - Python not working - downloading multiple files

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I wanted to download multiple files from an open-source web page --> "https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/0e33071d-9891-4009-970c-5aa26da5e31a". written below logic in python and I can able to download all files. however, web driver is not being quit after all files are downloaded. It is waiting and going to hung. I was unable to run anything after the below logic as it goes indefinite wait(hung). How to get quit the loop once all the files are downloaded.

```
#step-1:to get list of files:
data_url_page = requests.get("https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/0e33071d-9891-4009-970c-5aa26da5e31a", verify=False)
files_list = []
soup = bs(data_url_page.content, "lxml")
for table_div in soup.find_all('div', class_='ui-datatable-tablewrapper'):
    files_td = table_div.find_all('td', class_='NameColumn')
    for file_name in files_td:
        if file_name:
            files_list.append(file_name.get_text())

#step-2 : for download all files.
def http_file_downloader(data_url_files, files_list):
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    options.set_preference("service_log_path", "/home/myuser")
    options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "a/b/c/dir/")
    options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/force-download")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
    driver.get(data_url_files)
    try:
        for file_name in files_list:
            elem = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[text()='"+file_name+"']")
            elem.click()
    finally:
        driver.quit()

# calling above method
http_file_downloader("https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/0e33071d-9891-4009-970c-5aa26da5e31a", files_list)
```

Comment: You are missing a quotation mark in the line: options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "a/b/c/dir/). Can you fix that and see if anything changes?

Comment: that was basically a typo, I edited my code. Its is not an problem. Thanks for catching though